# Why can't I shove an instance of a class into a variable from a do_action hook?

Tags: plugins, filters, hooks, actions

I have a situation where I would like to grab an instance of a class from plugin B and put it into a variable in plugin A.

*Plugin A* *(This Doesn't Work)*:

```
/* Plugin A */
$class = do_action( 'get_class' );
$do_stuff = $class->do_stuff(); // throws error
```

*Plugin B*:

```
/* Plugin B */
add_action( 'get_class', array( MyClass, 'get_instance' ) );

/* Plugin B class (maybe separate file) */
class MyClass {

  public static function get_instance() {
    $class = new self;
    return $class;
  }

  ...

}
```

When I attempt to do this, the `$do_stuff` line of plugin A throws an error:

```
Call to a member function do_stuff() on null
```

However, when I use `apply_filters` and `add_filter` in lieu of `do_action` and `add_action`, it works.

*Plugin A* *(This Does Work)*:

```
/* Plugin A */
$class = apply_filters( 'get_class', null );
$do_stuff = $class->do_stuff(); // no error
```

*Plugin B*:

```
/* Plugin B */
add_filter( 'get_class', array( MyClass, 'get_instance' ) );

/* Plugin B class (maybe separate file) */
class MyClass {

  public static function get_instance() {
    $class = new self;
    return $class;
  }

  ...

}
```

Why?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just instantiate an object of type `MyClass` when you need it, inside of plugin "A"?

Comment: @CC, in this particular situation, I am not the owner of plugin "A," but am a contributor to it. As a feature enhancement, they want other plugin developers to be able to hook in to their plugin with a custom class that has specific logic for doing something with a file type not already handled by plugin "A."